# If $(X,d)$ is complete and $U$ is an open subset, then $U$ is metrizable in a complete way.

Tags: general-topology

If $(X,d)$ is complete and $U$ is an open subset, then $U$ is metrizable in a complete way.

The following hint is given:

> Show that the $W(f)$ the graph of $f(x)=d(x,X \setminus U)^{-1}$ is closed.

What do I have to prove, because I'm not seeing clear, we want to extend the completeness of the space $X$ in an open subset, the problem I think are the accumulation points, because Cauchy sequences does not have the limit. I only want what do I have to prove, I think with this function we create a distance.

Thanks

Comment: The idea is that $U$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $X\times \mathbb{R}$. We know the product is complete, hence its closed subsets are complete.

Comment: $d(x,y) + |f(x) -f(y)| defines a metric on $U$. If a sequence in $U$ is Cauchy under this new metric, it must already converge under $d$ inside $U$, as $f$-terms blows up otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For $x, y\in U$ put $\delta (x,y):=\max \{d(x,y);\, \dfrac{d(x,y)}{d(x,y)+ d(x,X\setminus U)+d(y,X\setminus U)}\}.$

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach.

Lemma: Let $(X_1,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$ be metric spaces and let $f:X_1\to X_2$ be continuous. For $p,q\in X_1$ let $$e(p,q)=d_1(p,q)+d_2(f(p),f(q)).$$ Then $e$ is a metric on $X_1$ equivalent to $d_1.$ (That is, $d_1$ and $e$ generate the same topology.)

When $X_2$ is the reals and $d_2$ is the usual metric, we can write $e(p,q)=d_1(p,q)+|f(p)-f(q)|.$

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $Y$ an open subspace of $X.$ Obviously if $Y=X$ then $Y$ has a complete metric. If $Y\ne X$ let $f(p)=1/d(p,X$ \ $Y)$ for $p\in Y.$  Show that $f$ is defined (because $X$ \ $Y$ is closed and non-empty.)

(i). Show that $f:Y\to \mathbb R$ is continuous.

(ii). By the lemma, $e(p,q)=d(p,q)+|f(p)-f(q)|$ is a metric on $Y$ equivalent to $d|(Y\times  Y).$

(iii). If $(p_n)_n$ is an $e$-Cauchy sequence then $(p_n)_n$ is a $d$-Cauchy sequence because $d\leq e$. Since $d$ is a complete metric on $X$ there is a unique $p\in X$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(p_n,p)=0.$

Show that $p\in Y$ by showing that if $p\not \in Y$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m>m'>n}|f(p_{m'})-f(p_m)|=\infty,$ a contradiction to the $e$-Cauchy property of $(p_n)_n.$

(iv). Since $d|(Y\times Y)$ and $e$ are equivalent metrics on $Y$ they have the same set of convergent sequences. So $\lim_{n\to \infty}e(p_n,p)=0,$ with $p\in Y.$ So $e$ is a complete metric on $Y$.

Remarks:(1). To show that two equivalent metrics have the same set of convergent sequences, note that in a metric space the sequence $(p_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $p$ iff $\{p\}=\cap_{n\in \mathbb N} Cl(\{p_m:m\geq n\})$,and that the closure operator ($Cl$) is determined by the topology.....(2). The idea of the proof, when $Y\ne X,$ is to obtain a continuous $f:Y\to \mathbb R$ such that whenever $r\in \overline Y$ \ $Y$ and $(p_n)_n$ is a sequence in $Y$ converging to $r,$ then $(f(p_n))_n$ is an unbounded sequence.